Separate table of contents Appendices
For my report, I need a separate table of contents for my appendices. After contacting the helpdesk, they provided me with this code, which indeed works :) ;
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\newcommand{\listappendixname}{Contents Appendices}
\newlistof{appendix}{loa}{\listappendixname}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\apptocmd{\appendix}{
  \xpatchcmd{\ttl@addcontentsline}
    {\addcontentsline{toc}}
    {\addcontentsline{loa}}{}{}
}
\makeatother

In the document body:
\appendix
\phantomsection % so that "Appendix" hyperlink in TOC is correct
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix}
\listofappendix

However, now I need to make my Chapters bolded in this list op Appendices, but my sections and subsections not. Can someone help me how to do this?
I tried this, but this does not work;
% Manually adjust the formatting for appendix entries in TOC
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\textbf} % Make chapter numbers bold
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\bfseries} % Make chapter titles bold

Thanks!
'
Kind regards,
Lea

Welcome. // Hm, what do you think we can do with your collage of code snippets? Here's some kind of guideline to start with your snippets and arrive at something we'd like to see posted here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that/10137#10137 . Thank you

Hi, sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Snippets?

Snippets: the 3 code fragments. If you copy one or all to a new file and compile, it won‘t succeed. Once it does, in reverse, you provided all info we need. Just follow said process and you‘ll be fine.
